# Android - List items do not refresh immediately

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I created a class activity after which inherit two activity. It looks as follows:

```
public abstract class VlcMediaPlayerList extends RoboActivity {
    public final static int AUDIO = 1;
    public final static int VIDEO = 2; 

    @InjectView(R.id.audio_list_view)
    ListView listView;

    public static ArrayList<ImageWithTwoText> list = new ArrayList<ImageWithTwoText>();

    public ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vlc_media_player_list);
        adapter = new ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        addListenerOnItemList();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (intent != null) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            ImageWithTwoText file = null;
        try {
            file = (ImageWithTwoText) extras.getSerializable(FileChooserAcitivity.FILE_TYPE);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        }
        Log.i("FILECHOOSER", String.valueOf(list.size()));
        if (file != null) {
        list.add(file);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    }

    /**
     * Add File method called when addButton is clicked. Start activity
     * FileChooserActivity for result as file
     * 
     * @param ImageButton
     *            view
     */
    public void addFile(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FileChooserAcitivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(FileChooserAcitivity.FILE_TYPE, getMediaType());
        startActivityForResult(intent, getMediaType());
    }

    /**
     * Clear the list when clearButton is clicked
     * 
     * @param View
     *            view
     */
    public void clearList(View view) {
        list.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.clear_list), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Add listener on list
     */
    public void addListenerOnItemList() {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
            PlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.PLAYER_ELEMENT,
            list.get(position).getTitle());
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }

    protected abstract int getMediaType();
}
```

One class that extends the abstract class as follows:

```
public class VlcMediaPlayerAudio extends VlcMediaPlayerList {

    @Override
    protected int getMediaType() {
        return VlcMediaPlayerList.AUDIO;
    }

}
```

The problem occurs after calling onActivityResult () which is taken ImageWithTwoText object representing the element of the list. After calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged (), this element is not added to the list.
Note! After exiting the activity (the return key) and re-entry to the same activity previously added element is already in the list

This is code for ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter:

```
public class ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public final static String TITLE_KEY = "title";
    public final static String SUBTITLE_KEY = "subtitle";
    public final static String IMAGE_RESOURCE_KEY = "imageResources";

    private final List<ImageWithTwoText> imageWithTwoTextList;
    private final Context context;

    /**
    * Class constructor
    * 
    * @param context
    */
        public ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter(Context context, List<ImageWithTwoText> imageWithTwoTextList) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_view, getArrayListOfTitles(imageWithTwoTextList));
    this.context = context;
    this.imageWithTwoTextList = imageWithTwoTextList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent, false);
    TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
TextView subTitleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    ImageWithTwoText currentElement = imageWithTwoTextList.get(position);

    titleView.setText(currentElement.getTitle());
    subTitleView.setText(currentElement.getSubTitle());
    imageView.setImageResource(currentElement.getImageResource());

    return rowView;
}

private static List<String> getArrayListOfTitles(List<ImageWithTwoText> imageWithTwoTextList) {
    List<String> listOfTitles = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (ImageWithTwoText imageWithTwoText : imageWithTwoTextList) {
    listOfTitles.add(imageWithTwoText.getTitle());
}

return listOfTitles;
}
```

}

Comment: Problem solved! I had to change the type ArrayAdapter after which inherits ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter and pass this ArrayList to the constructor of the parent
     
`public class ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageWithTwoText> {`
and
`super(context, R.layout.row_view, imageWithTwoTextList);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your constructor for the adapter, you are calling the base constructor like this:

```
super(context, R.layout.row_view, getArrayListOfTitles(imageWithTwoTextList));
```

This is passing the result of

```
getArrayListOfTitles()
```

to the underlying list stored by the adapter, which is a copy of your provided list. This means that changes you make to the list in the activity are not being made to the copy of the list held by the adapter.

Ahh, your comment beat my edit by about a minute! Glad it is solved!